# How to render HTML code passed inside a variable that is returned from the backend in Angular

Tags: html, angular, binding

I am passing an html code inside a variable from the server to the frontend.
However I am getting the text of the code itself instead of the expected html that I need to render. Here is the sample code that illustrates the example:

HTML code returned from the backend:

`img = '<a href="someLink" class="avatar"><img src="./assets/mira.png" class="img1" /></a>';`

Binding made in the frontend

`<span style="background-color:#ffffff;  padding:3px 11px; margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;">{{y.img}}</span>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  template: `
              <span style="background-color:#ffffff;  padding:3px 11px; margin: 5px; border-radius: 4px;"
                    [innerHTML]="img">
              </span>`,
})
export class Example {

  private img = '';

  constructor() {
    // mocked data returned from the server
    this.img = '<a href="someLink" class="avatar"><img src="./assets/mira.png" class="img1" /></a>';
  }

}
```

The idea here here is to bind `innerHTML` instead of using interpolation in order to modify the DOM structure and render the needed link returned from the backend.